# How to update Future map?

Tags: java, object, asynchronous, polymorphism, future

I have two maps one has Future and another has  has values.  I am trying to have two maps hidden behind one accessor method.

I tried:

```
@JsonIgnore
private final Map<String, Future<Object>> additionalFutureContext = new HashMap<>();

@JsonIgnore
private final Map<String, Object> additionalContext = new HashMap<>();

public <T> void addAdditionalContext(final String key, final T context) {
    if (context instanceof Future) {
        additionalFutureContext.put(key, context.get);
    } else {
        additionalContext.put(key, context);
    }
}
```

But this is not working. I am new to Java, can someone explain what I am doing wrong here ?

The error I am getting :

```
 error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             additionalFutureContext.put(key, context.get());
    [javac]                                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method get()
    [javac]   location: variable context of type T
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in method <T>addAdditionalContext(String,T)
    [javac] 1 error
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you show an example?

Comment: @akuzminykha We need to have both the future version and a non-future version. The future version handles registered futures and non-future will have String, Boolean values.

Comment: The else branch should say `additionalContext.put(key, context);`  (The `.put` is missing)

Comment: To make the code compile, you can try `additionalFutureContext.put(key, ((Future)context).get());` but keep in mind that will block until the future is completed.